# View VSCode and Android Emulator side by side on MACOS

Tags: macos, android-emulator, visual-studio-code

How can I setup VSCODE and Android Emulator side by side in full screen mode. Currently I am not in full screen mode on Vscode, as following, Note that it's not in full screen mode.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to apple.stackexchange.com.